# CakePHP Migrations Path and Migration Table Name?

Tags: php, cakephp, database-migration

This is my first time dealing with anything related to CakePHP. I'm attempting to use CakePHP Migrations to handle version control for future database updates, and there are three different configuration options that I've been trying to track down but haven't been able to find.

1. How do you change the name of the table that CakePHP creates to track applied migrations?
2. How do you change the path that migration files are stored in?
3. How do you change the path that seeds are stored in?

I've found all of those options for the instance of Phinx that CakePHP Migrations uses, but changing them doesn't seem to affect anything. Is it even possible to change these things? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Answer to your question 1:-
You can change the table name directly in your DB, then you can run the command bin/cake bake migration_diff YourFileName.  It will generate a new migration file by comparing the current Migration schema-dump file and your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin\cake migrations help migrate
```

You will see "-s, --source=SOURCE   The folder where migrations are in".  Same thing for the seeding.